# Jpype: "Can't start the AWT because Java was started on the first thread."

Tags: java, jpype

I'm using Jpype to use a java class into a python script.
The java class involves the use of AWT library: and this seems to be the problem.

This the python script:

```
import jpype
import os.path
import threading

jarpath = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'build/jar')
target=jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.ext.dirs=%s" % jarpath)
Capture = jpype.JClass('Capture')            # Capture is the class, contained in ./ folder
t = Capture(50,354,90,90,130,650,"num",36);  # create the instance
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

So I'm just trying to instantiate the class, and just exit.
This the java class. I'm reporting only the code that is causing error:

```
class Capture {

    public Capture(int x, int y, int width, int height, int mouseNextX, int mouseNextY, final String fnamestart, final int countmax) {
            //...
            images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
            getImages(fnamestart,countmax);  //THIS is the problem
}

    // reference to getImages() method:
    public void getImages(String fname, int countmax) {

        images.clear();
        for(int i=0; i<=countmax; i++) {
            try {
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(fname+i+".bmp")); 
                images.add(img);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                images.add(null);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

This code, when running python script, raise me the following error:

```
 jpype._jexception.VirtualMachineErrorPyRaisable: java.lang.InternalError: Can't start
 the AWT because Java was started on the first thread.  Make sure StartOnFirstThread is
 not specified in your application's Info.plist or on the command line
```

Long story short, this is a known problem: Eclipse had "its own version", then solved. Unfortunately no one spoke about this problem relating to jpype.

I tried these solutions, that didn't worked:

- In python script, launching a thread before starting the JVM. And then starting the JVM in another thread.
- In python script, starting the JVM with the parameter `-XstartOnFirstThread`:

  ```
  target=jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-XStartOnFirstThread -Djava.ext.dirs=%s" % jarpath)
  ```
- In the java code: using the AWT method `invokeLater`, in the constructor:

  ```
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
          getImages(fnamestart,countmax);
      }
  });
  ```

I really don't know what to do, hoping that you will help me.
Thank you,

Giovanni

Answer (score 2):

Use this parameter:

```
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), '-Djava.awt.headless=true')
```

Answer (score 0):

`-XstartOnFirstThread` is exactly what you must ensure **not** to have on the command line. Launching a thread in python makes no difference, the problem lies with JVM's threads. `invokeLater` will also not make a difference -- the AWT run loop must execute on the first thread. This is a Cocoa-only restriction, so I suppose you are running this on a Mac.

Now, you should search for your problem by seeing exactly what command line was used to start the JVM and then trying to trace back to the root cause -- the code that generated that command line. JVM is being launched by a method outside your immediate control.

Comment: In my opinion it is a Jpype problem: i read the code which initializes the JVM, and it runs a java thread before passing it to a python class. This way, when I initialize AWT, it does it in a second thread. Although I will run my code on a Linux machine, and not on a MAC OSX as I've done since now. Hope that this will solve the problem! Thank you

Comment: The initialization of the AWT event loop is outside the client code's control, as far as I know, and the thread where you use AWT objects is not important. So the only reason for this error would be RunOnFirstThread. It does sound like a problem with Jpype.